# How to have two different text outputs w/ ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm using text forms while using pins. My code below:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<div class="center">
        <h1><strong><%= pin.description %></strong></h1>
      <h3><%= pin.description %></h3></div>
      <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), pin %>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="panel-heading center">
            <%= image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium) %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <h1><strong><%= @pin.description %></strong></h1>
        <h3><%= @pin.description %></h3>
```

I get the same text output when I create a pin and descriptions using that code. I've tried changing the **:description** method into something else but then I got an error saying I can't load the page. How can I solve this problem? Thank You

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131017222026) do

  create_table "pins", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "definition"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: you have two same field `description` in you model? i think you need rename this field something like `description_1` and `description_2`

Comment: yes.i have tried making my own, but they've not worked? is description a method by ruby? What field description can I use if I just want to display a title? Thanks :)

Comment: as per my understanding description is the field of pins table so `pin.description` is right approach now I can not understand you want to change the `description` method what do you mean it? if you do not want description then in pin model you can create an instance method  like this `def definition description end` and now you can access it `pin.definition` in spite of `pin.description`

Comment: wait so i've added another t.string called "definition" and switched it around with the extra "description". Yet it's still not working. I get "NoMethodError in Pins#Index"

Comment: wait so i've added another t.string called "definition" - this not work you need create  migrations to rename column on database

Comment: @user3134121 no see what I am telling you can acess your description field by a model instance method with a different name............in My example `definition` is actually getting `description` of that pin instance

Comment: in pin model add method `def definition  description end` and in view `<%= pin.definition %>` hope it is clear now

Comment: @RajarshiDas bad way. this is spike! just create migration and rename column on database.

Comment: @Monk_Code no other way...he wants description in different name..it is ridiculous to create a separate column for same value

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is your problem (your question really lacks context):

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

If you try and output fields on a form, you'll have to output the fields relating to your model's schema. For example, if you just type `f.text_field :my_name`, you'll get a `no method` error

As you've shown your schema, you could put a text field for any of the attributes your record has, such as:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :definition %>
    <%= f.text_field :definition, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

---

**No Method Errors**

A quick note on `no method` errors for you

Since Ruby on Rails is [Object Orientated](http://objectsonrails.com/), everything you do with it has to involve an object. The best example of this is [ActiveRecord objects](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) - they are a variable populated with table data

The reason why you see `no method` errors is simply because you're trying to perform an action or method on an object which does not support it

So if you have `@companies`, and try to perform `@companies.is_my_name_richard?` - it will likely come back with a no method error. The way around this is to ensure you only call the model's attributes (if you're outputting the variable), or only use functions which have been defined in the controller or model